# Prove $a + b\sqrt{2}$ is irrational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, irrational-numbers

Suppose that a and b are non-zero rational numbers. How can I show that $a+b√2$ is not a rational number. You may assume that $√2$ is not a rational number.

I thought that finding contradictions in $a+b√2=m/n$ might work, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: "Solve" for $\sqrt{2}$ in terms of $a,b,m,n$, obtain contradiction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT: Your idea of using proof by contradiction is fine. To try that, assume that $a+b\sqrt2$ is rational. This means that there are integers $m$ and $n$ such that $$a+b\sqrt2=\frac{m}n\;.$$ Solve this equation for $\sqrt2$ in terms of $a,b,m$, and $n$. Do you see what the contradiction is going to be? If not, the conclusion of the argument is spoiler-protected below; mouse-over to see it.

> We have $\sqrt2=\frac1b\left(\frac{m}n-a\right)$. The difference of two rationals is rational, and $\frac1b$ is rational since $b$ is rational and not zero, so $\sqrt2$ is the product of two rational numbers and is therefore rational. This of course contradicts the known irrationality of $\sqrt2$.

Comment: That's a lot of detail for a "homework" question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews a lot of detail should be given cause he dosen't know where to start.

Comment: Sorry, but if a person doesn't know where to start, let him know where to start, don't also show him the middle and end.

Comment: @ i will keep that in mind ^_^.

Comment: It’s not necessary to assume that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. I would offer a little less than you did, but probably more than Thomas, something like this: ‘Suppose that $a+b\sqrt2=\frac{m}n$ for some integers $m$ and $n$. Now solve for $\sqrt2$ in terms of $a,b,m$, and $n$; do you see why this yields a contradiction?’

Comment: @BrianM.Scott we are to prove that it is irrational, so by contradiction we should assume it rational, and i have written it with rational definition,am i wrong?, nevertheless, i appreciate ur advice and will keep in mind.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with your argument, except that ‘coprime rationals’ really ought to be replaced simply with ‘integers’. I was just suggesting how you might have turned it into a hint that would still have been likely to help the OP.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott do u mind editing the answer so that i could have a better understanding.

Comment: I’ve edited it into a hint with spoiler-protected full solution. Had I answered the question, I might have given just the hint at first and waited to see whether the OP needed any further help.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott how do you make something appear only when your mouse is on it?

Comment: @Ovi: Begin the line with `>!`.